# How to loop android camera recording

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

I need to record a video by 10MB chunks, for this i used `mMediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(1085760);`once it reached specified size i got the reslut video in `setOnInfoListener (In this case i received the file MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED`).

when this sate is reached recording was stopped, so i start the recording again. Due to this the camera view had a blink and the content loss also occur  (due to the time (less than 5 secs) taken for camera re-initialization.)

In [DailyRoads](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dailyroads.v&hl=en) they did exactly what my need, how they loop recording with out camera re-initialization.

Here is my code Snippet.

```
 mMediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(8485760);
 mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                switch (what) {
                    case MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED:
                        Log.e("MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED", what + "");
//                        stopRecordingVideo();
                        mThresholdReachListener.onMaxLimitReached(videoFilePath);


        stopRecordingVideo();


    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startRecordingVideo();
        }
    }, 100);

                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: nothing yet? Facing the same problem now, any hints would be appreciated!